# jQuery UI div drags behind other div

Tags: jquery, user-interface

My page has two columns (divs), first has a list of divs that need to be dragged to the second but the divs always disappear behind the second div...tries z-index but no success...

With a clone helper it works but I don't want to use that because I want to be sure the only drag it once...

I've searched a lot already but I can't seem to find the solution...probably missing a detail...

Thanks!

CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.columns{width: 45%;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        overflow: auto;}

#col2{border-left: 1px solid black;}

.detailStyle{font-weight: bold;}

.detailSimple{list-style: inside;
                font-weight: normal;}

.zeroSimple, .zeroStyle, .noImage{font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #900;}

.disabled{ text-decoration: line-through;
            color: #CCC;}

#dropit{ background-color: #DDD;
        border: 2px #CCC dotted;
        width: 95%;
        height: 50%;}

#dropit #title{color: #CCC;
                }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="col1" class="columns">
<h3>divs</h3>
</div>
<div id="col2" class="columns"><h3>Add</h3>
<div id="dropit"><div id="title">DRAG AND DROP HERE</div></div>
</div>
<script language="javascript">
$(function() {

    function getProductStyles(){
        for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
            div = $('<div/>', { id: "div"+i, html: "div: "+i});
            div.draggable({containment: "document", zIndex:1000, scroll: false , appendTo: "body", revert: "invalid", revertDuration: 100, cursor: "pointer"});
            $('#col1').append(div);
        }
    }

    getProductStyles()

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the `<div>`s are `relative`ly positioned within `col1` so can only be dragged inside that div. Making the `<div>`s absolutely positioned allows you to drag them around the entire window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if your drag & drop was already working or not, but the problem with the draggable disappearing behind the right column is this in your css #col2:

```
overflow: auto;
```

I created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hs86h/) without the overlflow.

Comment: Thanks. But I actually want the overflow because the idea is people picking items out a quite extensive left column and dragging it to the right...a scrollbar on the right wouldnt be ideal...

Comment: "...a scrollbar on the right wouldn't be ideal..."
But this is exactly what 'overflow:auto' does.
"If overflow is clipped, a scroll-bar should be added to see the rest of the content."
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: Well yes, I know, I want a scrollbar in the first column and a static second column so people can scroll column one and drag items from there to column 2. But that's just the problem, when I add overflow: auto and thereby the scollbar I have the problem stated earlier :)

Comment: I think there are multiple solutions:
- you can add a helper to your draggable like this
    $( ".selector" ).draggable({ helper: "clone" });
- on drag you can change the css overflow attribute and change it back on drop

Comment: that's actually a great idea :)
I deleted the column 1 overflow on start drag and reapplied it at stop drag...and it works. The only thing you have to keep in mind is that the initial overflow must be added by jquery, or els you can't delete it through .css('overflow','')

Comment: nice to hear you've got it going!